# PHP error reporting not working with nginx

Tags: php, windows, nginx

Little hard time with php-nginx environment setup and run, problem facing is php error reporting not showing in web page rest php nginx are working but only issue with instead of error browser showing white/blank screen. My nginx configuration.

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
       location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
php.ini

 display_errors
 Default Value: On
 Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19455466/1461181

Comment: Finally able to figure out the issue. just turn on the `display_errors` in ini file . ; `http://php.net/display-errors
display_errors = On`  May be be this could be helpful for someone facing same issue.